# C++: is the memory freed for the variable declared inside the loop

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

Lets say I have a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    vector<int> table(100000, 0);
    int result = some_function(&table);
    // ...
}
```

Is the memory of previous "table" instance is freed in each loop cycle?

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you mean by "memory freed".

At the end of each iteration, the destructor for the vector is called, and therefore the destructor for each contained element is called.  So you don't have a memory leak (if that's what your concern was).

But whether the memory is returned to the operating system is a different question; that's implementation-specific.  There are at least two levels of abstraction involved, the container allocator, and the standard `new`/`delete` implementation underneath that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; the `vector` is destroyed on each iteration (and created on each iteration).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the destructor of vector will free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. In this way the memory is reserved just once, but the `vector`'s value is 0:

```
size_t vector_size = 100000;
vector<int> table(vector_size);
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    memset( &table[0], 0, table.size() * sizeof(int) );
    int result = some_function(&table);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The `memset` is not necessary as the vector constructor will value intialize its elements.

Comment: @Jesse: no, it calls default constructor. The result is undefined. One more reason: this way the array is NULL in second loop, too.